# phpexcel error when use include_once, require_once?

Tags: phpexcel

I use phpexcel in my project, if i call my class by my function, excel file cannot open
I call my class:

```
$Model = loadModel('cpm','cpm',$this->registry);
```

My function:

```
function loadModel($com='',$class_name='',$registry=null) {
if (empty($com)){
    $com = 'admin';
}
$filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.class.php';
$file = PATH_MODEL.DS.$com.DS.$filename;

if (file_exists($file) == false){
    return false;
}
require_once($file);
if($registry != NULL){
    $model = new $class_name($registry);
}else{
    $model = new $class_name;
}
return $model;
```

}

When i change to

```
/*require_once($file);
if($registry != NULL){
    $model = new $class_name($registry);
}else{
    $model = new $class_name;
}*/
$model=true;
return $model;
```

it work. In my project, I use autoload:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
/*** get the component from the url ***/
$com = (empty($_GET['com'])) ? '' : $_GET['com'];

if (empty($com)){
    $com = 'admin';
}
$filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.class.php';
$file = PATH_MODEL.DS.$com.DS.$filename;

if (file_exists($file) == false){
    return false;
}
requine_once ($file);
```

}

I am not sure it is reason.
I don't found any error in log.
Any help, thank.

I found that if I require(once) or include(once) file in controler, excel file will be can not open.

```
class excelController extends baseController {
public function index(){
    require('abc.class.php');
    $this->registry->template->show('excel', false);    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that your autoloader is clashing with PHPExcel's autoloader. See section 3.2 of the developer documentation (entitled "Lazy Loader") for advice on registering your own autoloader with spl_autoload_register() so that the two can co-exist